# PHP - How do I make a function wait and return another functions value

Tags: php, xml, function, loops, children

So I have some XML I need to loop through children to find a childs value. The problem is the actual looping. The way I know of is making a function, and if there is a child, use the same function and loop through the children - and again and so fourth.

My problem is that it doesn't seem as if the function is waiting for the "child function" to finish before returning my value.

Is there a better way of doing this? I know there are callbacks but I'm unsure how I would implement it here

**Example XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<pages>
    <page>
        <title>Parent Page1</title>
        <id>0</id>
        <children>
            <page>
                <title>Child Page1</title>
                <id>1</id>
                <children/>
            </page>
        </children>
    </page>
    <page>
        <title>Parent Page2</title>
        <id>2</id>
        <children>
            <page>
                <title>Child Page2</title>
                <id>3</id>
                <children/>
            </page>
        </children>
    </page>
</pages>
```

**Example PHP**

```
$page = "Child Page2";
echo "The ID of " . $page . " is " . a($page);

function a ($title) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("pages.xml") or die("Failed.");
    return b ($xml[0], $title);
}

function b ($pages, $title) {
    $val;
    foreach ($pages as $page) {
        if($page->title == $title) {
            $val = $page->id;
            break;
        } else if ($page->children->children() > 0){
            $val = b($page->children->children(), $title);
        }
    }
    return $val;
}
```

Is outputting: `The ID of Child Page2 is`

Now I know the XML isn't perfect in this example but it's only a placeholder so you understand what I'm trying to do. I'm using SimpleXML on the XML if that helps in any way

**Solution**

The problem was that if `b();` returned in the first branch, but still needed to check other branches of children, the whole thing returned `null` or simply nothing at all.

My solution lower down works, but went with Swayze's answer because it's shorter and more effective (Saves saving variables)

Comment: Can you please include your `$pages` variable

Comment: There sorry, forgot to change from `$pages` to `$xml`

Comment: Is there any reason you're using an XML string? You can't `foreach` on a string. Also, you don't need to declare $val; at the top of function b.

Comment: I needed a way to save info and it seemed like the best option

I know, but just imaging it's using simpleXML, so it does correctl output as an array, I just wanted to explain the XML markup I'm using (parents and children)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function b ($pages, $title){
    foreach ($pages as $page){
        if($page->title == $title){
            // returns id regardless of how many loops in you are 
            return $page->id;}
        else if ($page->children->children() > 0){
            // call function if it has children
            return b ($page->children->children(), $title);}}
    // if nothing is found
    return 'no results';}
```

This is the simplest way providing there can only be one instance of each title..

If i have misunderstood you and there is the chance that there can be more than one result for each search than this method will only return the id of the first match it finds.

Comment: Like I said it's not working code, it was an example to show you how the XML is layed out

I'm using SimpleXML

Comment: the code i posted works fine.. try it, the problem you were having is because you need to break the cycle when you find the result

Comment: Sorry about that, I have that in my code too, I just forgot to add it to my example

Comment: I can see your edit, but would that work? Your call to b() isn't being saved to any variable, so even if it did find something wouldn't it just be lost?

Comment: Aah I missed the "return $page->id"

This is much better and probably quicker than my saving as variables

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php

$page = "Child Page";
echo "The ID of " . $page . " is " . a($page);

function a($title) {
    $pages = [
        [
            'title'    => 'Parent Page',
            'id'       => 0,
            'children' => [
                [
                    'title'    => 'Child Page',
                    'id'       => 1,
                    'children' => []
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
    return b($pages, $title);
}

function b($pages, $title) {
    foreach ($pages as $page) {
        if ($page['title'] == $title) {
            $val = $page['id'];
        } else if (count($page['children']) > 0) {
            $val = b($page['children'], $title);
        }
    }
    return $val;
}
```

I wouldn't use XML here if you don't need to. This is a crude example using arrays, but it works for what you're trying to do. Let me know if this works for you. If you like object notation, you could turn the array into an object, or use classes (preferred).

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm trying to do. I added a few extra children and it still worked, busting my theory that a function that `returns` will in fact wait if another function has been called

Comment: Yes, PHP functions are ran synchronously so you won't run into that issue. Also, if I answered your question, could you mark my answer? Thanks man!

Comment: Ooh ok, thank you for that answer, that means there is something else wrong with my code! Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simplify the job just using xPath:

```
function b( $xml, $title )
{
    $val = Null;
    $pattern = '//page/title[text()="'.$title.'"]/..';
    if( $found = $xml->xpath( $pattern ) ) $val = $found[0]->id;
    return $val;
}
```

You can also modify it just for eventually that there are more than one identical titles:

```
function b( $xml, $title )
{
    $val = array();
    $pattern = '//page/title[text()="'.$title.'"]/..';
    foreach( $xml->xpath( $pattern ) as $node )
    {
        $val[] = $found[0]->id;
    }
    return $val;
}
```

xPath pattern explanation:

```
//                      Search following pattern no matter where it is
page/title              <page> with child <title> with
[text()="'.$title.'"]   node value = $text
/..                     select parent node
```

Comment: Interesting, I'll study the code and perhaps adapt it into my code later on

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem. The problem was that because I have many branches (many parents with children), once my loop had gone through the first branch and found nothing, it returned `null` to the function which also returned `null` back to the start.

I was able to fix this by adding a simple `if ($received != null)` like this

```
function b ($pages, $title) {
    $val;
    foreach ($pages as $page) {
        if($page->title == $title) {
            $val = $page->id;
            break;
        } else if ($page->children->children() > 0){
            $received = b($page->children->children(), $title);
            if ($received != null) { // Important
                $val = $received;
            }
        }
    }
    return $val;
}
```

Where I put my comment, you can see that the final return is forced to wait for the rest of the foreach and doesn't just use the first `null` it receives

Comment: if you are only looking for one result you don't need to keep passing $val through the function loop.. its overly complicated and unnecessary... you simply need to return the value when it is found, or return that no value is found once it is finished.

Comment: But if I need to find a single value from multiple branches of children then I need to keep looping through parents and their children

Or is there a better way or doing that?

Comment: you can still loop through and search all children, even if it goes multidimensional, without passing the variable around.

i will edit my original answer to show you what i mean.